# Show excel file in web page

Tags: c#, excel

I have created an excel file using EPPlus library, is there a short way to show it in the webpage without writing lots of codes ?

Comment: can you convert it to google docs and show as google worksheet?

Comment: convert it to PDF and then show - most browser can deal with PDF these days...

Comment: Is the spreadsheet purely for presentation purposes, or do you want it to still be updatable by the viewer?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, it is just a report with some data and images which users need to export to excel, however if I create this report using epplus, then I wonder how to keep it on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to embed your report as a PDF or as a large PNG/Jpeg.

Another solution would be to embed a PDF using pdf.js

http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/

This allows javascript to render a PDF without using any additional plugins, etc. (although it does need a HTML 5 browser)

http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html